# How do I align my initial conditions?

Tags: align

I'm trying to align my initial conditions (bottom two lines) to match the top ODEs.

```
 \begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align} \nonumber
  \begin{rcases}
     \dv{x}{t} = v \\
    \dv{v}{t} = \frac{-kx}{m}+Asin(\omega t) - bv
  \end{rcases}
  \\
  \begin{rcases} \nonumber
 x(0)=-2 \\
v(0)=1
  \end{rcases}
\end{empheq}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. Please especially make clear where `rcases` and `\dv` are defined.

Answer (score 2):

**edit:** partly considered @marmot comment

like this?

[image]

it is not perfect ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}\nonumber
&  \begin{rcases}
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}(t)}  = v                                 \\
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}(t)}  = \dfrac{-kx}{m}+A\sin(\omega t) - bv \\
  \end{rcases}          \\
&  \begin{rcases}\notag
            x(0)   = -2\hphantom{,k+A\sin(\omega t) - bv } \\
            v(0)   = 1
  \end{rcases}
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

note: since mwe is not known, i anticipated the  `\dv{x}{t}` can be own defined command, there fore i emulate it with suspected definition. however, such command is defined in `physics` package (not used in my mwe).

Comment: The macro `\dv{x}{t}` very likely comes from the `physics` package, see my answer below, and it could be that you replaced by something that does not resemble the output of the macro.

Comment: @marmot, could be ...  but this should tell as op with mwe, if it is from `phisics` package or it is defined by her/him :-)

Comment: I agree that the OP should provide an MWE. It's just that the output makes perfect sense if one uses the physics package (and becomes even better if one replaces `sin` by `\sin` ;-). Looks like I ws 2 seconds ahead of you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a better way than doing it "by hand".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
 \begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align} \nonumber
  \begin{rcases}
     \dv{x}{t} &= v \\
    \dv{v}{t} &= \frac{-kx}{m}+A \sin(\omega t) - bv
  \end{rcases} 
  \\
  \begin{rcases} \nonumber
 x(0)&=-2 \\
v(0)&=\makebox[0pt][l]{1}\hphantom{\frac{-kx}{m}+A \sin(\omega t) - bv}
  \end{rcases} 
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `drcases`, as suggested by Bernard

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
 \begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align} \nonumber
  \begin{drcases}
     \dv{x}{t} = v \\
    \dv{v}{t} = \frac{-kx}{m}+A \sin(\omega t) - bv
  \end{drcases} 
  \\
  \begin{drcases} \nonumber
 x(0)=-2 \\
v(0)=\makebox[0pt][l]{1}\hphantom{\frac{-kx}{m}+A \sin(\omega t) - bv}
  \end{drcases} 
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with Ti*k*Z.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {\strut};}
\begin{document}
 \begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align*} \nonumber
     \dv{x}{t} &= v&\tikzmark{1} &\\
    \dv{v}{t} &= \frac{-kx}{m}+A \sin(\omega t) - bv&\tikzmark{2} &
  \\
 x(0)&=-2 &\tikzmark{3} &\\
v(0)&=1&\tikzmark{4} &
\end{empheq}
\tikz[remember picture, overlay,decoration={brace}]{%
\draw[decorate,thick] (1.north) --
(2.south) node[right,midway] {(initial conditions on velocities)};
\draw[decorate,thick] (3.north) --
(4.south) node[right,midway] {(initial conditions on positions)};}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe with `drcases`?

Comment: @Bernard I agree that this will look better (`d` stands for `\displaystyle`, right?) but I am not sure if that will lead to a simpler solution to the alignment problem.

Comment: It was only for the general look. The derivatives are much smaller than the initial conditions, which looks odd, semantically.

Comment: @Bernard I fully agree, what is even worse is that the alignment `&`s cause bad spacing. But since I knew that Zarko will post an answer in 2 seconds, I had to hurry up ;-) . OK, more seriously, I think one may need to create a new environment for this, or, alternatively, draw the braces with Ti*k*Z (which introduces its own problems). Anyway, thanks for your input, I'll be happy to use `drcases` in a revision of my answer.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks for the edit. I do not understand how that happened. There was also a wrong figure, which I fixed. Really strange.

Comment: @marmot, you are welcome! maybe your computer not completely wake up from hibernation  :-)

Comment: @Zarko It's so cold down here that my claws are really stiff.